# Exporting beamer with org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

How do I generate a beamer presentation from an org-mode file? What beamer features can I use in my file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Beamer export](http://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-export.html) is very similiar to [LaTeX export](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-export.html#LaTeX-export) in Org-Mode, all you need to do is hitting `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf` or `C-c C-e l P` from the Org buffer you're working on.

[The majority of options](https://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-specific-export-settings.html#Beamer-specific-export-settings) are taken from the LaTeX export except for `BEAMER_THEME` and `BEAMER_COLOR_THEME`.

Other than that there are a few Beamer-specific commands one can use to have Beamer-only code and to control its overlays, [see the manual for further details](https://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-specific-syntax.html#Beamer-specific-syntax).